# I have a list of names, some of them are fake, I need to use NLP and Python 3.1 to keep the real names and throw out the fake names

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have no clue of where to start on this. I've never done any NLP and only programmed in Python 3.1, which I have to use. I'm looking at the site http://www.linkedin.com and I have to gather all of the public profiles and some of them have very fake names, like 'aaaaaa k dudujjek' and I've been told I can use NLP to find the real names, where would I even start?

Comment: NLP probably isn't as useful for names, considering that they don't generally follow an established grammar nor pattern of sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difficult problem to solve, and one which starts with acquiring valid given name & surname lists.

How large is the set of names that you're evaluating, and where do they come from? These are both important things for you to consider. If you're evaluating a small set of "American" names, your valid name lists will differ greatly from lists of Japanese or Indian names, for instance.

Your idea of scraping LinkedIn is on the right track, but you were right to catch the fake profile/name flaw. A better website would probably be something like IMDB (perhaps scraping names [by iterating over different birth years](http://uk.imdb.com/search/name?birth_date=1946-01-01,1946-12-31)), or Wikipedia's lists of [most popular given names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_popular_given_names) and [most common surnames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_common_surnames).

When it comes down to it, this is a precision vs. recall problem: in order to miss fewer fakes, you're inevitably going to throw out some real names. If you loosen up your restrictions, you'll get more fakes, but you'll also throw out fewer real names.

Answer (score 1):

Several possibilities here, but the most obvious seems to be with HMMs, i.e. [**Hidden Markov Models**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model).  The [**NLTK**](http://www.nltk.org/) kit includes [at least] one module for HMMs, although I must admit I never used it.

Another possible snag is that AFAIK, NTLK is not yet ported to Python 3.0

This said, and while I'm quite keen on using NLP techniques where applicable, I think that a process which would use several paradigms, including some NLP tricks may be a better solution for this particular problem.  For example, storing even a reduced dictionary of common family names (and first names) in a traditional database may offer both a more reliable and more computationally efficient way of filtering a significant portion of the input data, leaving precious CPU resources to be spent on less obvious cases.

Comment: When reading answers on NLP-questions on SO, I more and more get the feeling that HMMs are everybody's hammer when natural language is the nail. Not targeted towards your answer, just a subjective impression I get lately.

Comment: @ferdystschenko: Quite possible! Indivs and communities tend to become "hammer happy"; I'll keep an eye on this trend on SO.  Better yet, `let's use HMMs to analyze this further!` [just kidding ;-) although other Bayesian approaches may be productive, the lack of a genuine "beat" (sequence) in SO postings probably disqualifies HMMs as a plausible solution.].  On a serious note, the implicit sequential nature of language (observed at many levels, like letters, here, words, with POS-tagging etc.) explains the relative success of HMMs in NLP apps (along with the Bandwagon & the Matthew effects)

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid this problem is not solveable if your list is even only minimally ‘open’ — if the names are eg customers from a small traditionally acting population, you might end up with a few hundred names for thousands of people. but generally you can hardly predict what is a real name and what is not, however unusual an arabic, chinese, or bantu name may look in a sample of, say, south english rural neighborhood names. i mean, ‘Ng’ is a common cantonese surname, and ‘O’ is common in korea, so assumptions may fail. there is this place in austria called ‘fucking’, so even looking out for four letter words is no guarantee for success.

what you could do is work through a sufficiently big sample of such names and sort them out manually. then, use all kinds of textprocessing tools and collect metrics. maybe you can derive a certain likelyhood for a name to be recognized as fake, maybe it will not be viable. you will never go beyond likelyhoods here, though.

as an aside, we used to use google maps and the telephone directory for validating customer data years ago. if google maps could find the place, we called the address validated. it is clear that under stricter requirements, true validation must go much further. let’s not forget the validation of such data is much more a social question than a linguistic one.